# Firearm restriction while open carrying in Florida

Tags: united-states, florida, second-amendment

A person is going fishing out into the Everglades. They make the decision to open carry a firearm.

- Are there any restrictions as to the *type* (Shotguns, Rifles, Pistols, etc) of firearms a person can open carry?

Comment: Besides "weapons already legal in the state of Florida"?

Comment: The question is limited to legal weapons and focused on _IF_ there are limitations on the type of firearm that can be open carried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the state of Florida, any weapon that can be legally owned can be open carried while fishing.